# NDSolve and results of the previous computations

Tags: numerical-integration, differential-equations

I want to solve following system of ODEs:

$
\Bigg\{
\begin{array}{}

\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}=\frac{2W_b}{Rsin(\theta)}(1-\frac{C}{\gamma})+\frac{\nu}{\pi R^2}\frac{\partial C}{\partial Z}
\\
\frac{\partial R}{\partial t}=\frac{W_b}{\gamma sin(\theta)}

\end{array}
$

Where $W_b=k_bC_h(1-\frac{C}{C_h})^{\frac{4}{3}}$ and $\nu, k_b, C_h, h, \gamma, \theta$ are constants.

It is known that:

$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial Z}=\frac{C_i-C_{i-1}}{Z_i-Z_{i-1}}
$, where $Z_i-Z_{i-1}=h$ and $h$ is a constant.

So, the first equation become this:
$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}=\frac{2W_b}{Rsin(\theta)}(1-\frac{C}{\gamma})+\frac{\nu}{\pi R^2}\frac{C_i-C_{i-1}}{h}
$

My question is how can I get the result of previous computation, namely $C_{i-1}$?

Here is the mathematica code I wrote:

```
Wb[C_] := kb*Ch*(1 - C/Ch)^(4/3);
system := {
  c'[t] == (2*Wb[c[t]])/(r[t]*Sin[theta])*(1 - C/gamma) + v/(Pi*r[t]^2)*(c[t] - ?? )/h,
  r'[t] == Wb[c[t]]/(gamma*Sin[theta]),
  c[0] == 0, r[0] == 0.15};
solution = First@NDSolve[system, {c, r}, {t, 0, 25900000}, Method -> "BDF"];
```

**UPDATE**:   Simplified version of the problem.

This is a model based on a [plug flow reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug_flow_reactor_model).
$
\Bigg\{
\begin{array}{}

\dot{x} = \frac{c_1 x f(x)}{y} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} \\ 
\dot{y} = c_2 f(x)

\end{array}
$

Where c1 and c2 are constants. This is a model of a physical process and it was shown that `z` dimension is quantified by a chunks of a constant size `h` and `x` is monotonously increasing, so $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta z}=\frac{x_i - x_{i-1}}{h}$

```
f[x_] := ...;
system := {
  x'[t] == c1*x*f[x[t]]/y[t] + (x[t] - ?)/h,
  y'[t] == c2*f[x[t]],
  x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0.15};
solution = First@NDSolve[system, {x, y}, {t, 0, 25900000}, Method -> "BDF"];
```

Comment: First of all, you can already solve for R(t) by hand. Second, the remaining equation probably should have C replaced by C_i. Is that what you mean? You will then also need the initial conditions for all C_i, I would guess. With that, you would have a coupled system of first-order equations in time for the C_i.

Comment: I've updated the question. Wb is a function dependent on C, I'm not sure if it possible to solve it by hand.

Comment: I believe your assignment to system should just use Set (=) rather than SetDElayed (:=).  You just need to define a list of equations, not a function.

Comment: What is the connection between the $C_i$ and $C$? You write that $\partial_Z C=(C_i-C_{i-1})/h$; but what's $C$? a fn of $t$ and $Z$? and what is $Z_i$? Maybe you could try giving a clearer and minimal example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: $C_i$ is the result of computation on current step $C_{i-1}$ is the result of computation on previous step. So in mathematica $C_i$ is equivalent of `c[t]` and $C_{i-1}$ is something like `c[t-step]` and I'm asking what it really is.

Comment: @Andrew and $Z$ is therefore the time, that earlier was called $t$? Also, could you please put a simplified problem here?

Comment: @acl no Z is a dimension of a chemical reactor which is constant. Ok, I'll make simplified version in a minute.

Comment: @Andrew Yes that would help!

Comment: So, initially $x=x(y,z)$ but you would like to replace this 2d function by a finite number of 1d functions, ie, you'd like to discretise the $z$ direction by hand. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Andrew then you need to solve a set of differential equations for $x_i(y,t)$ (ie, a set of variables, not a single var) and $y(x_1,\ldots,x_N,t)$, whereas you're trying to set the problem up for a single $x$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll dig in that way then!

Comment: Look up Delayed Differential Equations in the documentation (howto/SolveDelayDifferentialEquations). Your ?? will be x[t-h]. Also figure out the correct initial condition because you will need to specify it for a range of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems (from the comments) that what you want to do is this: initially x=x(y,z) but you would like to replace this function of 2 vars by a finite number of functions of 1 var, ie, you'd like to discretize the $z$ direction by hand. This means that you need to solve a set of differential equations for the $x_i(y,t)$ (a set of functions, not a single fun) and $y(x_1,\ldots,x_N,t)$.

You're trying to set the problem up for a single $x$, and that is the problem.

**OLD ANSWER**

(I think this is neat so I'll leave it here for now)

I very likely misunderstood you. If, however, I understood correctly the question, it is something like: Suppose I have $y'(t)=f(y)$ and ask mathematica to solve it numerically. How do I inspect the values of $t$ used?

The answer is to rig the ODE so that you can peek at the values mathematica evaluates, as follows:

```
ClearAll[f];
upT = 2*Pi;
f[y_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := (Sow[{t, y}]; -Sin@y)
```

Here I define $f(y)=-\sin(y)$, but in a way that allows me to watch which values are passed to $f$ by `NDSolve` (the `Sow` bit). Then:

```
points = (sol = NDSolve[
        {
         y'[t] == f[y[t], t],
         y[0] \[Equal] 1
         },
        y,
        {t, 0, upT}
        ]) // Reap // Last // Last;
```

solves the ODE, collecting the values of $y$ and $t$ passed to $f$ by `NDSolve`. Then plot the solution, along with the points at which $f$ was evaluated:

```
Plot[
 y[t] /. sol,
 {t, 0, upT},
 Epilog :> {Red, PointSize[.015], Point[points]},
 ImageSize -> 640
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not sure if I am answering the right question though.

It's also interesting to look at the size of the steps taken:

```
ListPlot[
 Differences[points[[All, 1]]],
 ImageSize -> 640,
 BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 20,
 AxesLabel -> {"i", "t[i]-t[i-1]"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

so they are not all equal (not all $h$), sometimes the solver goes backwards etc. Of course this will depend on the solver you use.

Comment: You know, you could have used `EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{t, y[t]}]` as an `NDSolve[]` option setting, don't you?

Comment: @J.M. yes, but I am not the most elegant of programmers :)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax has me a bit confused.  SetDelayed (:=) looks off to me.  Typically one uses this to define functions.  I think you want Equal (==) where you have the system of equations and Set (=) where you assign the value of the expression to "solution".

Does this get you any closer (I replaced your "??" with "x")?

```
solution = First@NDSolve[{
c'[t] == (2*Wb[c[t]])/(r[t]*Sin[theta])*(1 - C/gamma) + 
  v/(Pi*r[t]^2)*(c[t] - x)/h, 
r'[t] == Wb[c[t]]/(gamma*Sin[theta]),
c[0] == 0,
r[0] == 0.15
}, {c, r}, {t, 0, 25900000}, Method -> "BDF"]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, no, the problem is that I don't know what `x` should be.